# Selenium + python + Googledriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using python with selenium for web scraping along with chrome driver in headless mode (with no ui). The thing is that i click to a href button and that action does not download the pdf file that i want. But the thing is that maybe it downloads but i don't know where. It doesn't do anything, no error, nothing.

The same action works perfectly with the gui mode.

Any suggestions?.

Thanks in advance!.

Comment: Please post your code attempt you help you better.

Comment: The HTML of the page would be helpful as well.

Comment: I can access the web session perfectly, and the last thing i do is this:

pdf = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[4]/a")

pdf.click()

I click the element basically.

Click on the element must download the file to the download folder, but it doesn't.

Comment: downloading files is disabled by default in headless mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a default directory for downloading files when initializing the chromedriver:

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
# Set the target subfolder based on the current working directory
dl_folder = '/downloads'
dl_location = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), dl_folder)

# Add the headless argument
chrome_options.add_argument('headless')

# Prepare a dict with additional preferences. This is where the magic happens:
prefs = {"download.default_directory": dl_location}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)

# launch the driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= '/path/to/executable', chrome_options= chrome_options)
```

After that you click something that initialises the download

```
exportbtn = driver.find_element_by_id('exporter-csv')
exportbtn.click()
```

And then you retrieve the latest added file from the folder. For example if it is a csv load it to a dataframe:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
list_of_files = glob.glob(dl_location+ '/*')
latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
df = pd.read_csv(latest_file)
```

I'm not familiair with a way to get the filename or file directly. If there is any I'm curious to hear about it.